# Efficient way to scan through array based on time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I am currently trying to show elements of an array based on the time of a video..

For example
lets say a user wants the background color of a website to be RED when a video is at 00:30-1:20 (minutes:seconds) and the background to be website to be BLUE when the video is at2:00-3:00.

I currently have an array filled with the beginning times of each color changes, and a index.
The begging time will be compared to the current time of the video. If the current time is >= the beginning time then the background will change to the color of the index.
The current time will now be compared to the ending time, once the ending time is passed the index will increase...

Basically something like this.

```
var index =0;
beginningTime[]; 
endingTime[];
colors[];

If(vid.currentTime>=begginingTime[index] && vid.currentTime<endingTime[index])
{
 background.color=colors[i];
}
if(vid.currentTime>endingTime[index])
i++;
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficent way to do this? or any tips on a better way to do this?

Comment: When are you executing this? Are you using any timeouts or video events? Do you have a loop around there or are you just repeatedly executing it?

Comment: You can try this: http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-docs/effects/ there should be something you can use.